# Create and populate TreeMap in one line

Tags: java, android

Like an array `new Integer[]{ 1, 2, 3 }`, can I create and populate a TreeMap using just one line?

```
// I want to use it in situations like this:
this.lookFor( new TreeMap( {...} ) );
```

Any chances for `HashMap` or `LinkedHashMap` too?

Comment: Double brace initialization. While you're at it, write your whole program in one line.

Comment: `TreeMap` is a map which works with `(key, value)` pair. I can't think of about one line, initialization and adding elements at the same time.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no built-in syntax for *specifically* initializing maps.  However, you can take advantage of a special syntax known as "double brace initialization".

```
Map<String, Integer> map = new TreeMap<String, Integer>() {{ put("one", 1); put("two", 2); put("three", 3); }};
```

The outer pair of braces means that you are declaring and initializing an [anonymous inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that extends `TreeMap`.  The inner pair of braces represents an [instance initializer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/initial.html), code that is run when an instance is created.

Answer (score 2):

The brace notation in

```
new Integer[]{ 1, 2, 3 }
```

is a special notation for array types.

The brace notation in

```
new TreeMap( {...} )
```

won't compile.

The brace notation in

```
new TreeMap(  ) {}
```

creates an anonymous subclass of `TreeMap`. What you can do is do this and then immediately use an instance initializer to add things to the `Map`.

```
new TreeMap() {{this.put(1,2);}}
```

Obviously, use the types that apply to your use case.

This is known as double brace initialization.

Answer (score 0):

I do it like this:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import static java.util.Map.entry;
...
public class MyClass {
    private static final SortedMap<String, String> MY_MAP = Stream.of(
            entry("key1", "value1"),
            entry("key2", "value2"),
            ...,
            entry("keyN", "valueN")
    ).collect(toMap(
            Entry::getKey, 
            Entry::getValue, 
            (v1, v2) -> v2, 
            () -> new TreeMap<>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER)
   ));
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you can use this sample code

```
this.lookFor(new TreeMap<Object,Object>(){
    @Override 
    public boolean isEmpty() {
        /*
        *some code
        */
    }
});
```

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question.